# terraform hcl object transformation

Tags: terraform, hcl

have an object like

```
variable "user_role" {
  type = map(list(string))
}

user_role = {
 user_a: ['role_a', 'role_b', 'role_c']
 user_b: ['role_a', 'role_c']
 user_c: ['role_c']
}
```

what I currently have is just simple flatten into:

```
role-user = flatten([
    for member in keys(var.user_role): [
      for value in var.user_role[member] : {
        role = value
        member = member
      }
    ]
  ])
```

need to transform it to have a role as a key.

```
role_user = {
  role_a: ['user_a', 'user_b']
  role_b: ['user_a']
  role_c: ['user_a', 'user_b', 'user_c']
}
```

any ideas on how to reach that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example, it seems like you are describing the functionality of [the built-in `transpose` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/transpose.html):

```
locals {
  role_user = transpose(var.user_role)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows (don't forget about [...](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/function-calls.html#expanding-function-arguments)):

```
role-user = merge([
           for user, roles in var.user_role:
            {
              for role in roles: user => role...
            }
           ]...)
```

Comment: seems to be the same,- user as a key. but I need a role to be a key. I've changed it a bit but with no luck. 
`user_role = {
user_a: ["role_a", "role_b", "role_c"]     
user_b: ["role_a", "role_c"]     user_c: ["role_c"]  
 }    
role_user = merge([   
for user, roles in local.user_role:   {   
for role in roles: role => user...   
}   ]...)`
--------------- 

# terraform console
> local.role_user
{ "role_a" = [ "user_b", ] 
"role_b" = [ "user_a", ] 
"role_c" = [ "user_c", ] }

Comment: sorry, for the mess, dont understand why new line characters ignored

Comment: @JohnnieWalker Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. You already accepted other answer. Maybe ask there?